# iOS VoIP Push Notification delay

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, voip

I'm working on a voip app using PushKit.
I can receive voip push notifications in all possible app states (e.g. background, foreground, active, inactive).
Using PushKit I followed all steps described in this blog:
http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ios/create-native-ios-app-can-receive-voip-push-notifications/

Everything works well and the notification is received very quickly but I discovered a serious problem (sistematic) with Voip PushKit.
When the app is in a suspended state and the screen is locked and black (more than 10 minutes inactivity), my app wakes up after several minutes (at least 2 minutes).

Note:

I tested PushKit with the latest iOS version: 10.0.2 on iPhone6S and iPad.

The payolad sent is:

```
apsd(PersistentConnection)[85] <Notice>: 2016-10-28 17:57:15 +0200 
apsd[85]: <APSCourier: 0x155ee3a70>: Received message for enabled topic 'it.eggzero.centric.voip' with payload '{
aps =     {
    alert =         {
        "action-loc-key" = "<null>";
        body = "incoming call";
        "loc-args" =             (
        );
        "loc-key" = "<null>";
    };
    badge = 0;
    category = INVITE;
    "content-available" = 1;
};

}' onInterface: NonCellular  for device token: NO  with priority (null)
```

I'm using a sandbox certificate to test it, with a production one the behaviour is different?

Thanks,
Elio

Comment: Do you use LocalNotification? Pushkit payload doesn't come in notification center.

Comment: I'm using remote notification and before my app is waked up I see in apsd (apple Push Service Demon) this payload coming from Apple Server.